# Group_by similar values - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to group values in one array based on the proximity of values and according to a given interval between values.

```
a=[1,2,5,7,20,25,50,53]
```

interval of 5 for example:

```
a=[[1,2,5,7],[20,25],[50,53]]
```

if I change the interval to 2:

```
a=[[1,2],[5,7],[20],[25],[50],[53]]
```

Ive tried to solve this using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) however without success.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe group based on `mod interval`?

Comment: So 1 is within the group of 7 in the first example (7-1 is 6) because it is close to 2 which is close to 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job, even if there probably is a nicer solution (as always in `Ruby`) :

```
def group array, diff
  array.sort! # To remove if you're sure your array will always be sorted
  # array = array.sort # could be a better solution if you don't want your array to be modified in place
  res = []
  subres = []

  array.each do |elt|
    if subres.count == 0 || elt - subres.last <= diff
      subres << elt
    else
      res << subres
      subres = [elt]
    end
  end
  res << subres unless subres.empty?
  res
end

a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 20, 25, 50, 53]

p group a, 5
p group a, 2
```

will output

```
[[1, 2, 5, 7], [20, 25], [50, 53]]
[[1, 2], [5, 7], [20], [25], [50], [53]]
```

as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
def group(a, n)
  prev = a.first
  a.slice_before { |x|
    (x - prev > n).tap { prev = x }
  }.to_a
end

a = [1,2,5,7,20,25,50,53]
group(a, 5) # => [[1, 2, 5, 7], [20, 25], [50, 53]]
group(a, 2) # => [[1, 2], [5, 7], [20], [25], [50], [53]]
```

Comment: Thanks falsetru. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def group(array, interval)
  result = [[array[0]]]
  array.inject do |x, y|
    if y - x <= interval
      result.last << y
      else
        result << [y]
    end
    y
  end
  result
end

a=[1,2,5,7,20,25,50,53]

p group(a, 5) # => [[1, 2, 5, 7], [20, 25], [50, 53]]
p group(a, 2) # => [[1, 2], [5, 7], [20], [25], [50], [53]]
```

Comment: If you use `result[-1]` or `result.last`, you don't need to keep track of `count`.

Comment: Ah, very true! Your answer is so much shorter anyway, but I confess I'm still trying to get my head around it. I wasn't familiar with either #slice_before or #tap.

Comment: Thanks Kal. Me too. Didnt know about slice_before.